# `bind` does not run user-defined function

Tags: fish

The fish docs say you can run a list of commands using the syntax

`bind <char> cmd1 cmd2 ...`

including some speciall commands listed at https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#bind.

Writing a plugin that has key bindings,

I added

`` bind '&' `backward-delete-char` on_ampersand ``

to `fish_user_key_bindings.fish`, but it resulted in no behavior - the `on_ampersand` function was not called, and neither was `backward_delete_char`. Without `on_ampersand`, it works.

The docs don't suggest anything about why this behavior could occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in fish - you can't combine the input-buffer editing commands with your own commands. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3683.

The workaround is to use the `commandline -f [function]` syntax in a user defined function to access those functions specially available to  `fish_user_key_bindings` :

```
function on_ampersand
    commandline -f backward-delete-char # or whatever
    [your code]
end
```

Comment: It's not really a bug as it is working as intended. But the behavior is inadequately documented. Patches to improve the documentation are welcomed.